# Hours range stored as text in a single column - filtering

Tags: mysql

I'm working on an old project where long time ago I decided to store opening hours as text in the database. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `places` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `place_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `monday` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tuesday` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wednesday` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thursday` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `friday` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `saturday` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sunday` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Up until now it was fine because this data was used only for informative purposes. Values inside monday-to-sunday columns are being filtered so that they have to strictly match the pattern: HH:MM-HH:MM, for example "08:00-17:30", while the NULL value means that place is closed on particular day.

However, now there is requirement to filter places by their opening time. Something like "**show places that are open now**". I could, and I have already prepared, query that will use SUBSTR and STR_TO_DATE functions to split opening times, but I'm not sure if this isn't going to kill my database. I'm expecting circa 100'000 rows and the original table is a "little" more complicated :)... this one is just an example.

Working (yet) SQL:

```
SET @currentTime := '16:00:00';

SELECT * 
FROM `places` 
WHERE `monday` IS NOT NULL 
AND STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(`monday`, 1, 5), '%H:%i') <= @currentTime 
AND STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(`monday`, 7, 5), '%H:%i') >= @currentTime
```

What do you think about it? Is there a nicer way to do that using existing DB structure or should I forget about such half measures and change the structure immediately?

Comment: I would convert the time values to smalldatetime data types to make use of the suite of functions available to datetime data types (Useful for comparing times etc)

Comment: @Grantly: Thanks. But did you mean to replace:

`STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(`monday`, 1, 5), '%H:%i')`

with:

`CAST(SUBSTR(`monday`, 7, 5) as TIME)`

or simply rebuild the whole structure?

Comment: I would rebuild the whole structure so you can use the MySQL datetime functions.  Add new datetime fields, use a script to convert the string time values into the new fields, then delete the string fields

Comment: (Better to have a small pain now, than a large pain when your DB is under load :)